# Elevation angle using PyEphem

Tags: python, gps, pyephem

my question is somewhat generic but I'd like to know whether anyone has developed a script that calculates the elevation angle of the satellite using RINEX files using Python, and in particular with PyEphem? I'd like to probe to see what is already out there...
Cheers, pymat.